# The idea behind the \outer primitive

Tags: tex-core

It seems that this primitive was designed for the purpose that in case programmers forgot to put `}` in the end of the definition of a macro (in this case, TeX thought all characters until the end of the current file is a part of the definition of this macro). I cannot grasp the idea behind this macro, especially that sentence

> When a macro definition is preceded by `\outer`, the corresponding control
> sequence will not be allowed to appear in any place where tokens are being absorbed
> at high speed.

How to use `\outer` and what's the meaning of `high speed` by DEK?

Comment: it has no justification at all:-), must be the worst part of the TeX design. LaTeX doesn't  use it, luatex has a setting to disable it completely. It's an error-detecting feature that has generated orders of magnitude more errors than it ever deteced.

Comment: Well, most people here use LaTeX, but if you use TeX the exact way Knuth used it you would likely find it useful...

Comment: Actually the "how to use" part is already covered in [macros - When is it appropriate to use \outer? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2012/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-outer) . I don't think there's one that ask for exact semantic though (because... people can generally figure it out by testing?)

Comment: @user202729 I also use LaTeX, I am jusst curious about how the underlying engine works.  For me, TeX is a programming language, its engine is a compiler. this language is harder than C++ :)

Comment: (technically) not really, the engine is TeX, LaTeX is a "framework" on top of it, and it's more of an interpreter than a compiler.

Comment: @user202729 I don't think latex or plain makes much difference here, it's not useful in plain TeX either

Comment: I think latex or plain is like standard library seen in other programming language.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't use `\outer` it never does anything useful (despite the fact that I use it in the `bm` package:-)

"High speed" here means when TeX is tokenizing input without evaluating it. So for example in plain TeX

```
\def\foo{...\newcount\abc  \abc=42 ...}
```

You get an error as the replacement text of `\foo` is being collected, as `\newcount` is outer in plain.

lots of macros reasonably want to embed `\newcount`. eg a `\newthorem` construct probably needs to allocate a theorem counter. The plain TeX version has to use contortions like `\csname newcount\endcsname` just to avoid the outer `\newcount` token, which is outer just to discourage use of `\newcount` in a macro that is used often, in a way that would allocate a counter on each use, and run out of count registers.

Comment: Preventing unbounded absorption of tokens by placing an `\outer` token (like in `bm`) is a reasonable use-case I'd say.

Comment: @HenriMenke yes sure, what I meant is "it never does anything useful, unless you are me:-) or more seriously never on a user callable command. The bm case is a command that should never appear at all so outer is a cheap way to catch it,

Comment: If I understand the TeXbook correctly, this was in some way also the original intention of user-facing `\outer` macros. With 1980s computing power you didn't want to wait for 20 minutes until TeX had reached the end of the document to tell you that you're missing a `}`.

Answer (score 5):

How to use `\outer`? Keep at arm's length from it: it bites.

Suppose you want to exploit `\proclaim` but you also want to automatically number your statements. You do

```
\newcount\statementcounter
\def\statement#1{%
  \global\advance\statementcounter by 1
  \proclaim#1 \number\statementcounter. \ignorespaces
}

\statement{Definition} This is the definition of foo.

\statement{Theorem} This is the statement of a theorem about foo.

Now text follows.

\bye
```

It ought to work, you say. Well, no: you get a very bizarre error message

```
Runaway definition?
#1->\global \advance \statementcounter by 1
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning definition of \statement.
<inserted text>
                }
<to be read again>
                   \proclaim
l.5   \proclaim
               #1 \number\statementcounter. \ignorespaces
?
```

OK, how to do it? Simple:

```
\newcount\statementcounter
\def\statement#1{%
  \global\advance\statementcounter by 1
  \csname proclaim\endcsname#1 \number\statementcounter. \ignorespaces
}

\statement{Definition} This is the definition of foo.

\statement{Theorem} This is the statement of a theorem about foo.

Now text follows.

\bye
```

Apparently, Knuth doesn't use automatic numbering and is pleased to do it by hand (or he's able to type in papers directly without ever changing his mind about the order of statements).

Well, this was not what I was actually trying to do: I wanted to do automatic numbering using the AMS-TeX version of `\proclaim` that suffers from the same problem (I was typesetting the book written by my “Maestro”, whom I owe so much).

In `plain.tex` you also find

```
\def\tabalign{\us@true\m@ketabbox} % non-\outer version of \+
\outer\def\+{\tabalign}
```

which seems to mean that Knuth himself got bitten by `\outer`.

What does “high speed” mean? Basically, it means “macro expansion is suppressed”, see [When does tex do macro expansion?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644175/when-does-tex-do-macro-expansion/644179#644179)

Indeed, you can try

```
\newcount\statementcounter

\edef\statement#1{%
  \global\advance\statementcounter by 1
  \noexpand\proclaim#1 \noexpand\number\statementcounter. \ignorespaces
}

\statement{Definition} This is the definition of foo.

\statement{Theorem} This is the statement of a theorem about foo.

Now text follows.

\bye
```

and you'll see no error about `\outer`, because `\proclaim` is seen when TeX *is* doing macro expansion.

If you want to “de`\outer`ize” `\proclaim`, you can do

```
\newcount\statementcounter

\let\OUTERPROCLAIM\proclaim
\edef\proclaim{\noexpand\OUTERPROCLAIM}

\def\statement#1{%
  \global\advance\statementcounter by 1
  \proclaim#1 \number\statementcounter. \ignorespaces
}

\statement{Definition} This is the definition of foo.

\statement{Theorem} This is the statement of a theorem about foo.

Now text follows.

\bye
```

There are other methods; this doesn't rely on knowing the actual definition of the `\outer` macro.

Comment: Your example inspired me to implement another macro.

Comment: I think it mean "sometimes he need to use \+ within another macro and is okay with selecting either of them depends on the need" instead. It does serve the "error checking" part if you do that

Comment: @user202729 After having used plain TeX or AMS-TeX for several years, I still don't understand what `\outer` should do, besides hindering programmers. Well, I see nothing too strange in declaring `\bye` to be outer, even though I can imagine applications where `\bye` is in the replacement text of a macro. For `\+` or `\proclaim` there is no reason. And, indeed, Spivak removed all `\outer` commands in his LAMS-TeX extension of AMS-TeX.

Answer (score 2):

#### Meaning of "high speed"

Reading the book *carefully* helps.

In this case, it's explained right in the next sentence.

> An `\outer` macro cannot appear in an argument (not even when `\par` is
> allowed), nor can it appear in the parameter text or the replacement text of a definition, nor in the preamble to an alignment, nor in conditional text that is being skipped over.

Look up `\halign` for what "alignment preamble" means. "conditional text that is being skipped over" means e.g. if `\verb` were outer, then `\iffalse \verb|\fi| \fi` would be invalid <sub>(side note, the actual implementation stops at the first `\fi`)</sub>.

#### Usage

[section removed because of too much overlap with the old linked question.]