# About pdftex and stockwidth

Tags: pdftex, plain-tex

I use pdfTex and had a file with included graphics, by using

```
\input miniltx.tex
\input graphicx.tex
```

and all worked well.

Now I get a mistake like

```
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \@firstoftwo.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
<to be read again> 
                   \newdimen 
l.558 \@ifundefined{stockwidth}{\newdimen
                                         \stockwidth}{}
?
```

What is the use of \stockwidth and \stockheight and why are they not defined in /texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/pdftex.def itself?

Edit:
If pdftex.def says:

```
\@ifundefined{stockwidth}{\newdimen\stockwidth}{}
\@ifundefined{stockheight}{\newdimen\stockheight}{}
```

why is it not defined after this?

Comment: that is fixed, make sure you have the latest `graphics-pln`

Comment: https://github.com/latex3/graphics-def/issues/35

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/644380/the-idea-behind-the-outer-primitive#comment1605808_644380

Answer (score 2):

You are using an old version of `miniltx` the current version does not error.

You ask why `\stockwidth` is not defined after

```
\@ifundefined{stockwidth}{\newdimen\stockwidth}{}
```

Note the error is not an undefined command and not about `\stockwidth` it is `\newdimen`  which is the "`! Forbidden control sequence`".

In plain TeX `\newdimen` is declared as `\outer`, an entirely useless feature specifically to raise an error if the command is used in command arguments or conditional sections of code. `miniltx` now removes the `\outer` definition. `\newdimen` has never been `\outer` in LaTeX2e, so this is one more latex-ism that got added to `miniltx` to support the latest graphics code.

Updating texlive should fix the error.

Comment: Thanks, that was it.  I used the older version of miniltx.